Why the growth is exponential in Slow-start-phase (congestion control) even when we increase window size by only 1MSS with each ACK received
I want to know why do we consider congestion window size increase as exponential even though we are increasing it by only 1MSS at each ACK received (Transport Layer).
I have learned that in Congestion Control Mechanism, there are two phases -

Slow-Start Phase
Congestion Avoidance Phase.

Slow-Start Phase - We keep increasing Congestion Window size exponentially by 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,... and so on till threshold. But now I read that we increase the window size by only 1MSS with each ACK recieved. So wouldn't it become linear instead of exponential growth like - 1, 2 (1+1MSS), 3 (2+1MSS), 4 (3+1MSS)....and so on.
Where is the exponential growth here?? I don't get this.
This is more like Congestion Avoidance Phase where I am getting linear growth to avoid congestion.
Can anyone help me understand this with a clear example and what am I missing.
Edit: I got what I was missing and what was not being told clearly in books. I am answering my own question. Hope it helps someone.

I saw it, but it doesn't help sir. There you can see its cwnd+1, cwnd+2, cwnd+4. What I am concerned about is why does this 1, 2 and 4 keep getting added when it clearly says we increase size by only 1MSS, but here they are adding 2, 4 and more MSS as they receive more ACK.

Increasing the window increases the packet rate. If you increase the window for each packet - which takes less and less time as rate increases - the window increases exponentially over time.
